# Hi could you assist with this python assignment?

Tags: python-3.x

## trying to make a bill

```
price = {'sugar' : 45,'rice': 60,'tealeaves':450,'wheat':40,'oil':100};
ordered = {'sugar':2,'rice': 3,'tealeaves':0.5,'wheat':4,'oil':1}

total = list()

for k,v in price:
    value = price[k]*kgsordered[k]
    print (k,':',value)
    total.append(value)

print('*'*4,'CG Grocery Store','*'*4)

print('Your final bill is ₹',total.sum())

print('Thank you for shopping with us!!')
```

## traceback coming

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "C:\Users\user\Desktop\My  Python Files\curiosity gym python
>   HW.py", line 4, in 
>       for k,v in price: ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)

Comment: maybe you meant `for k, v in price.items():`. Also, please format ALL your code with \`\`\`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, you have to use `.items()` to iterate through a dictionary.

Secondly, you were using `kgsordered[k]` instead of `ordered[k]`, which gives you an error, since `kgsordered` isn't defined.

And in the end, in you want to calculate the sum of all the elements in a list, you do it by doing  `sum(total)`, where `total` is your list

```
price = {'sugar' : 45,'rice': 60,'tealeaves':450,'wheat':40,'oil':100};
ordered = {'sugar':2,'rice': 3,'tealeaves':0.5,'wheat':4,'oil':1}

total = list()

for k,v in price.items():
    value = price[k]*ordered[k]
    print (k,':',value)
    total.append(value)

print('*'*4,'CG Grocery Store','*'*4)

print('Your final bill is ₹',sum(total))

print('Thank you for shopping with us!!')

# output

sugar : 90
rice : 180
tealeaves : 225.0
wheat : 160
oil : 100
**** CG Grocery Store ****
Your final bill is ₹ 755.0
Thank you for shopping with us!!
```

Comment: @Aditya please consider accepting the answer if it helped you